# Concurrency in distributed Task Queue (Producer/Consumer)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, distributed, task-queue

My application(Java) randomly produces some tasks and asynchronous consumed by distributed background threads.

I don't have distributed lock solution such as [ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org) at present.
I don't have any 3rd party message queues.

I use a database as the task queue and the consumed results are also saved in the database, which shared access by all consumers/producers.

I have some code like this:

Consumer:

```
while(true) {
  // block the thread and wait from producer's notify
  // my producers would produce MANY work items but only notify each consumer ONCE.
  waitProducer();

  // consume the queue
  while(database.queueNotEmpty()) {
    // consume each work item and remove from database queue
    consumeAll();
  }
}
```

Producer:

```
for(...) {
  database.enqueue(work[i]);
}
// notify all consumers
notifyAllConsumer();
```

Apparently the code above has concurrent bugs. I have 3 questions:

1.How to avoid distributed consumers consume the same task?
(about the line: "consumeAll()")
or reduce the duplicated compute. consume one task multi times won't be a bug but less efficient in my case.

2.How to avoid the queue is NOT empty but no consumer active? the sequence would be:
one consumer & one producer sample:

- Consumer: while(database.queueNotEmpty()) // queue is empty, break
  the while loop
- Producer: database.enqueue(work[i]);      // produce a task
- Producer: notifyAllConsumer();            // notify the consumer, but
  it is already active
- Consumer: waitProducer(); // hang the thread but still has work to do

---

3.Any best practice for this problem? especially in pure java.
Is a third party message queue or something like zookeeper a must? 
Less lock or no lock is preferred; efficient is prefer to correctness in my case.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use a `BlockingQueue`? They are designed for this kind of job

Comment: @fge is BlockingQueue works only in one JavaVM? my producers would be in different servers.

Comment: Well, nothing prevents you from using one as a relay between your producers and consumers; there are also solutions like Terracotta which allow sharing a POJO (with locking and all) across several VMs.

Comment: How do you implement `waitProducer()`, `consumeAll()` and `notifyAllConsumer()`? Apart from that you'd better go with any of the production-ready MQs available.

Comment: @pingw33n The 3 implementations are beyond the question. If we assume the 3 methods are implemented correctly, my problems still exists.

Comment: Actually if they are implemented correctly they would for example ensure the fetch operation is atomic and no two fetches would return the same message. They same applies for the other methods. Your problems are to be solved inside these methods.

Comment: @fge Thanks! I will check Terracotta later. However, the tasks in my case should be persistent, in memory only is not enough while restarting the servers.

Comment: @pingw33n even if i can ensure every functions above atomic, the 2nd problem still exists? in fact, consumeAll would be very complex and time consuming (that's why it is in async threads) and won't be atomic in practice.

Comment: You have 2 options , the first is synchronized at db/central server level, in your case you can make an atomic removal of the item or write any dirty bit to signal consumed item, second option is to directly synchronize the nodes\servers via message passing

Comment: @shaydel thanks. sync at db level is an option but not good for my case. any recommendation about the later option for java web app?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) in this case.

[LinkedBlockingQueue tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/linkedblockingqueue.html)

You can use take() / put() methods and if you want to wait with timelimit you can use offer(), poll() and peek().

I also used this in similar kind of problem.